# Unable to find element by xpath inside form

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a web application, where I actually try to find xpath and click on the cell. But i am getting error.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='form_grid_0']/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]").click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpirN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4qBZ.png)

Code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-main/app-submenu/div/app-tab/nav/ul/li[2]/a").click()

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-main/app-submenu/div/app-tab/section/div/app-gridwrapper/div/div/div/div[1]/div/p/button").click()

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-main/app-submenu/div/app-tab/section/div/app-gridwrapper/div/div/div/app-form/section/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[21]/app-form-date/div/input").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/app-root/app-main/app-submenu/div/app-tab/section/div/app-gridwrapper/div/div/div/app-form/section/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[21]/app-form-date/div/input").send_keys("05/01/2022")

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='form_grid_0']/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div[2]").click()
```

error at the last : for Form_grid_0

Comment: Could you provide with the website and the code you have written?

Comment: Sorry its the internal tool.

Comment: By your code I see that you are using some absolute xpaths, and long relative xpaths. Try to keep your relative xpaths as short as possible and do not use absolute xpaths at all. Try to find out the correct element with the relative xpath. For example, instead of `//*[@id='form_grid_0']/div[4]/div[3]/div/div/div2` there could be something like `//*[@id='form_grid_0']//*[@class='something']` etc.
Without inspecting elements, I can suggest only this much.

Comment: Also, check if there is any other line in DOM that pertains to the click that you are looking for.

Comment: That worked man. Thank you